# Why monger only update one record instead all the records in the list

Tags: clojure, monger

I have a function that takes in list of entry and save it to mongo using monger.
What is strange is that only the one record will be updated and the rest ignored unless I specify `multi:true`.
I don't understand why the multi flag is necessary for monger to persist all the updates to mongodb.

```
(defn update-entries
   [entries]
   (let [conn (mg/connect)
         db (mg/get-db conn "database")]
     (for [e entries] (mc/update db "posts" {"id" (:id e)} {$set {:data (:data e)}} {:multi true}))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The multi flag is necessary for multi updates, since that's what mongo itself uses. Take a look at documentation for [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). Granted, that's mongo shell, but most drivers try to follow when it comes to operation semantics.

Note that if `"id"` is unique, then you're updating one record at a time so having `:multi` set to `true` shouldn't matter.

There is, however, another issue with your code.

You use a [`for`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) comprehension, which in turn iterates a collection **lazily**, i.e. calls to `mc/update` won't be made until you force the realization of the collection returned by `for`.

Since `mc/update` is a call made for it's side-effects (update a record in the db), using  [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) would be more apropriate, unless you need the results.

If that's the case, wrap `for` in `doall` to force realization:

```
(doall 
    (for [e entries] 
         (mc/update db "posts" {"id" (:id e)} {$set {:data (:data e)}} {:multi true})))))
```

Comment: I originally used `doseq` but because I am not seeing the updates so I changed to `for` to see the output.
I understand what you explained and you said it yourself that because I am matching 'id' so setting multi:true should not matter -- however this is the problem I am trying to understand.

Comment: @SeymourCakes if you need the results, you can use `doall` instead of `doseq`. Anyway you need to force the sequence realization somehow.